# I want to shuffle 5 cards in an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shuffle

I have 5 cards in GabeObject[] cards. I want to shuffle and save these cards to GameObject[] cardshuffle. Something is wrong with this code. It shuffles same cards. How can I make it not shuffle same cards again? Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] cards;
public GameObject[] cardshuffle;
int i=0;
int j = 0;
int save=0;
int[] kayit = new int[10];
int kayit2;
public GameObject[] player1;
public GameObject[] player2;
public GameObject[] player3;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    kayit[0] = 20;
    while(i<5)
    {
        save = Random.Range(0, 5);

        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++ )
        {
            if(kayit[a] == save)
            {
                kayit2 = save;
         }
        }
        if (kayit2 != save)
        {
            cardshuffle[i] = cards[save];
        }
        else
            i--;
        kayit[i] = save;
        i++;
   }


        while (cards[j] != null)
        {

            player1[j] = cards[j];
            j++;

            Debug.Log(j);
        }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly?

Comment: Done. I hope I did correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this works thanks to Plastic Sturgeon.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] cards;
public GameObject[] tmp;

public GameObject[] player1;
public GameObject[] player2;
public GameObject[] player3;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    for (int t = 0; t < cards.Length; t++)
    {
        tmp[0] = cards[t];
        int r = Random.Range(t, cards.Length);
        cards[t] = cards[r];   
        cards[r] = tmp[0];

       }
        for(int i=0; i<cards.Length;i++)
        {
        player1[i] = cards[i];

        }

        }


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an int array to this method. It will shuffle the array:

```
void Shuffle(int[] texts)
{
    // Knuth shuffle algorithm :: courtesy of Wikipedia :)
    for (int t = 0; t < texts.Length; t++)
    {
        int tmp = texts[t];
        int r = Random.Range(t, texts.Length);
        texts[t] = texts[r];
        texts[r] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks perfect but i dont know how to implement this code :(.

Comment: I use cards as GameObject. Can you show me how to implement your code to this code? I want it to be inside of Start function.

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] cards;
void Start () {

}
}